# "plugin" to the facebook android app

Tags: android, facebook

Is it possible to write a plugin to the facebook android App ?

What I am trying to do : Allow the user to send some data to another App . 
Can anything from the android facebook app be passed on to another App in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a plugin architecture for Facebook, and in fact their app doesn't play well with Android in that there's no way to share content from the Facebook app with other apps. e.g. in Tweetdeck you can Share a tweet via email, SMS, etc but not from the Facebook app. I assume they re keen to keep the data within Facebook.

You could possibly write your own Facebook app that connects to the Facebook API and shows the data, in a way that can be shared.

Comment: thanks. My intention was to use what already exists and not re write the whole stuff again(Eg: the wall postings). Looks like I need to find another solution then.

Comment: You can easily do it the other way, i.e. write an app that can pass text to the Facebook app to be posted on the user's wall.